# An Exercise in Graph and Set Theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, set-theory, trees

**Exercise.** Let $n>2$ be a natural number. Define the simple graph $G_n=(V,E)$ as follows:
$$V=\{A\subset\{1,2,...,n\}:|A|=2\}\ , \{A,B\}\in E\iff A\cap B=\emptyset. $$
For which values of $n$ is $G_n=(V,E)$ connected?

**Attempt.** I could not solve the problem satisfying the above conditions, so I tried to simplify the problem and find out for which values of $n$ the graph $G_n=(V, E)$ is a tree, a minimally connected graph. But I still have not succeeded in finding some bounds for $n$. I cannot understand how can I make sure that $G_n=(V, E)$ is a connected graph and find the corresponding bounds of $n$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried, but I did not notice the pattern.

Comment: I would approach the problem by understanding the terms used in the statement. For example, the meaning of "simple graph", what does $\phi$ as well as $\lvert\cdot\rvert$ represents. I know that a connected graph allows any path between two vertices.

Comment: hint: if $n>5$, then for any subsets $A,B\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$ of size $2$ you can find $C\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$ with $|C|=2$ and $A\cap C=B\cap C=\varnothing$. (why?)

Comment: (@AndreasLenz in principle I very much agree with you, but in this case I think the small examples are misleading. for example if $n=3$ there are no edges whatsoever! and if $n=4$ every vertex has degree $1$)

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto A simple graph is a graph that allows to vertices share at most one edge, and no loops are allowed (an edge that connects a vertex to itself). $\phi$ represents the empty set; in this case, $A$ and $B$ do not intersect. Finally, $|\cdot|$ represents the set's number of elements.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I tought that these examples help to realize that connectivity increases with $n$ and identify the non connected cases, but probably you're right and my comment raises more confusion than it helps.

Comment: I would try to generalize n-Venn diagram to understand intersections among different sets given by nodes and edges.

Comment: I try to understand the intention of the symbolic statement: First: The vertices set corresponds to a subset of 1 to n elements, such that it contains only two elements. Second: A subset composed of edges A and B from set E. Finally, the first and second statements can happen only if A and B exhibit no intersections. Am I right? If so, I cannot even understand the interconnections between components of left hand-side and the right hand-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graph is connected for $n \geq 5$. As others have said in the comments, when $n = 3$ the graph has no edges and when $n = 4$ the graph has 6 vertices, but only two edges.

Now assume $n \geq 5$ and take two non-adjacent vertices. Without loss of generality, we may assume the vertices are $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,3\}$. A path between these two vertices is given by $$\{1,2\} \rightarrow \{4,5\} \rightarrow \{2,3\}.$$

EDIT: For $n = 4$, there are three edges. Thank you to @AtticusStonestrom for catching my mistake.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom You are right! Thank you for catching that.